# Custom validation Date c#

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, data-annotations

I want to create a custom validation for a datetime field.

There is my class Booking, with the field "Date" on which I want to put the validation :

```
    public class Booking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Restochoisi { get; set; }
        public int Nbpeople { get; set; }
        [CustomValidator]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Orga { get; set; }
    }
```

The class CustomValidator.cs :

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property |
  AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if ((DateTime)value < DateTime.Now)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the BookingController :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int restochoisi, int nbpeople, DateTime start, int orga)

    {
        var context = new BddContexte();

        var vm = new BookingViewModel()
        {
            Restos = new SelectList(context.Restos.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Nom"),
            Utilisateurs = new SelectList(context.Utilisateurs.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Prenom")

        };

        //ViewBag.result = restochoisi + " " + nbpeople + " " + datepicker + " " + orga;
        //dal.RestoById(restochoisi)
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int id = dal.CreerBooking(restochoisi, nbpeople, start, orga);
            return View(vm);
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong in my gait please ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? do you get an error? no errors?

Comment: I get an error in my function "CreerBooking" when I put a "wrong" date.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be using your model class with the validator

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Booking booking)
{
     // snip
}
```

Without that, I'm not sure how you think your custom validator would be working?!

Comment: With this modification, I don't have any error, but the modelstate is always false, even if the date is correct

Comment: @MatthieuVeron - `ModelState` will tell you what is not valid about your model then. Fix it.

Comment: ?? 

That is precisely the purpose of my question. I do not understand what is incorrect in my code, and that makes the modelstate does not return what I would like it to return

Comment: When `ModelState.IsValid` is false. Look at the value of `ModelState` in a debugger. It will tell you exactly what is not valid

Comment: By setting a breakpoint on that line and inspecting the value. I'm really not sure I can explain how to debug in a comment!

Comment: Thank you, it works. 
It cost me 3 points less on my "reputation", but at least it works!